# NSSlider: how to send value and action at the same time?

Tags: swift, cocoa, binding, slider, nsslider

I thought it would be simple, but seemingly it´s not.
I have a NSSlider from which the value I want to be shown in a label, like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIfDQ.png). With a setup as shown in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulSzY.png) it´s working fine, using a binding `takeIntValueFrom`. Now I want this slider to set a new UserDefaults value:

```
 @IBAction func sliderAction(_ sender: NSSlider) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(sliderOutlet.intValue, forKey: "sliderkey")

        print(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "sliderkey"))
    }
```

This actionfunc removes the `takeIntValueFrom`-binding. So in the end, it´s either or. Till now, I could not find a solution how to make it both work. Would be a pleasure to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of the label in `sliderAction`.

Or, for the more adventurous, bind (Bindings Inspector) the value of the slider and the value of the label to the Shared User Defaults Controller with the same key path. The action of the slider is not connected.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the the second part of your answer. This is really elegant.